# Зачем нужен dto mapper?

Tags: java, entity, dto

Зачем нужен dto mapper? К примеру ModelMapper. Во всех примерах классы dto и entity идентичны. Если нужно отдавать json с полями отличающимися от модели все равно нужно писать маппинг, зачем тогда использовать библиотеки? В чем выгода?
К примеру

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Иванов Иван Ильич",
            "status": "Председатель",
            "filter": [
                "дирекция" 
            ],
            "phones": [],
            "email": [
                "Ism@ya.ru",
                "aIB@mail.ru" 
            ],
            "image": "Ivanoff828",
            "thumbImage": "Ivanoff64" 
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Петров Петр Анатольевич",
            "status": "Заместитель",
            "filter": [
                "дирекция",
                "совет"
            ],
            "phones": [],
            "email": [
                "Sh@ya.ru",
                "sv@mail.ru" 
            ],
            "image": "Sh828",
            "thumbImage": "Sh64" 
        }
}
```

Entity описываются классом

```
@Entity
public class Contact extends BaseEntity {
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String patronymic;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Phone> phones = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Email> emails = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    private String position;
    private String organisation;
}

@Entity
public class Email extends BaseEntity {
    private String email;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;
}

@Entity
public class Phone extends BaseEntity {
    private String number;
    private String type;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;
}
```

Есть ли смысл в этом случае использовать готовый маппер dto или лучше писать свой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Библиотеки позволяют избавиться от написания избыточного кода в случаях, когда имена полей `DTO` и `DAO` объектов совпадают.

А еще если посмотреть в сторону библиотеки `MapStruct`, то увидите, что можно не писать кастомные конвертеры, а только при использовании аннотаций производить маппинг объектов.

Пример:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface UserMapper extends EntityMapper<User, UserDTO> {

    @Mapping(target = "userName", source = "name")
    User toEntity(UserDTO dto);

    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "userName")
    UserDTO toDto(User user);
}
```

Так сложилось в мире энтерпрайз джавы, что `DTO` объекты используются для сериализации данных и передачей их между системами, и соответственно для десериализации обратно в объект, то есть являются объектами передачи данных. `DTO` объекты не содержат поведения и не содержат методов бизнес логики.

Теперь мы можем говорить про `DAO` как об отдельном объекте, который является объектом, отражающем данные, например, баз данных, как это часто приходится и может содержать поведение, то есть иметь какие-либо методы для управления состоянием этого объекта или иметь бизнес логику.

Почему же есть `DAO` и `DTO`? Чтобы разнести ответственность, вот и все.

Comment: Если имена полей DTO и DAO объектов совпадают, то зачем тогда DTO? Чем отличаются объекты кроме приписки Dto к имени?

Comment: @AntonCharov дополнил ответ